# Using an svg object as a container for a Google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

As the title says I have an svg object and I want that object to contain a Google map instance. I was trying to do this the same way I usually do with divs or simple elements, using Javascript and `getElementByID` and placing the map inside the element. however this does not seem to work here. I have done a lot of searching but since Google uses svg for custom icons and overlays all the responses are related to that. I've mostly tried different approaches regarding where to put the `id="map_canvas` but nothing has worked.

My HTML with the svg as an object:

```
<div class="row map">

 <div class="span12">

    <object type="image/svg+xml" id="map_canvas" data="assets/map/MA_map.svg"></object>

 </div>

</div>
```

My JavaScript (this is currently in the `<head>` tag but I want to move it to the `.js` document):

```
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

And finally this is what my `svg` file looks like (created in Illustrator):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg version="1.1" 
 id="map_canvas" 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"

 viewBox="-79.892 94.942 960 599.864" 
 enable-background="new -79.892 94.942 960 599.864"
 xml:space="preserve">

<filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
<feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/> <!-- stdDeviation is how much to blur -->
<feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/> <!-- how much to offset -->
<feMerge> 
<feMergeNode/> <!-- this contains the offset blurred image -->
<feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> <!-- this contains the element that the filter is applied to -->
</feMerge>
</filter>

<path  
 id="map_canvas" 
 style="filter:url(#dropshadow)" 

 <path //lots of lines of code for the path />

 </svg>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to ultimately achieve?  Why are you trying to put a Google Map inside an SVG?

Comment: I want a google map to appear inside of a complex shape.I know how to use a regular div as a canvas for a map, but this is something different as per a client request.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions you can try:

1. Use an SVG `<foreignObject>` with a `<clipPath>` or `<mask>`.  I am not sure how well this will work though.
2. Use a CSS Mask (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks).
3. Create a maps `Polygon` that has the same colour as the background and which is the size of the map and has a hole the shape of your mask.
4. Cover the map with an `<img>` (eg. PNG) that has the same colour or texture as the background and which has a hole the shape of your mask.